# How to detect is Wine running from Linux or from mac OS environment in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, wine

I have a C++ application which runs using Wine for mac OS and Wine for Linux. I'm looking for a way to detect what's the host OS using C++.

The only thing I found is a way to detect if it's Wine or not (using wine_get_version), but I still need to separate mac OS and Linux runs.

Any ideas how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like there is a `wine_get_host_version` function in one of the ntdll but I'm not having luck finding documentation on it.

Comment: I believe, even when ran under Wine, you can still call native OS functions. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Please see this: http://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2016/03/27/detecting-wine-via-internal-and-legacy-apis/

Comment: Consider using [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) in your C++ application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @NathanOliver mentioned in the comments, you should use `wine_get_host_version()` for this. As with `wine_get_version()`, you need to use `GetProcAddress()` to get the function pointer from NTDLL. The C function signature for the function pointer would be:

```
void (CDECL *)( const char **sysname, const char **release )
```

You provide the address of two `const char*` variables and `wine_get_host_version()` sets them to point to two strings. The strings are those output by the `uname()` system library function. (If you're not interested in an output, it's safe to pass `NULL` for that parameter.)

For macOS, `*sysname` will be set to point to `"Darwin"`. For Linux, it will point to `"Linux"`, I believe. (It did on a couple of systems I tested, but I don't know how consistent that is.)